# Server Error on "/Forms/EditForm.aspx" Pages list cache permission check failed. Pages list cache permission check failed.  Pages list is missing?

Tags: permissions, publishing, publishing-page, editing-menu

I have a Sharepoint environment with two languages, english and german and now i got a little error on the german one.
If i click on "Edit Page" in the top ribbon i get the following error:

[image: Server Error Message]

Its not the Pagelayout or the Masterpage .. i tried this with Microsoft's and mine.. same error.
The developer dashboard tells me that there is an assertion or critical event "8wzx Unexpected Publishing" 
[image: Unexpected Publishing]

> ! Publishing Unerwartet 8wzx Pages list cache permission check failed.  Pages list with this URL is missing: Seiten
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleUtilities.DoesUserHavePageListPermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionsToCheck)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleNode.IsCurrentlyEnabled(AuthoringStates currentState)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.trimActionTreeForContext(ConsoleNode treeNode)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.trimActionTreeForContext(ConsoleNode treeNode)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.PopulateDataSource()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.GetHierarchicalView(String viewPath)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
>      at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

(Seiten is the german word for pages, and the name of the pagelist here)
Does someone has an idea whats the problem here?

PS: Found that error only one time on google but thats not the solution for my problem i guess: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/02/04/common-problem-nullreferenceexception-when-using-the-variationdatasource-on-a-sharepoint-master-page.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yep... This is the error you get if a Page-Library is broken.. :S
Its quite funny cause' the pages were still there, and i was able to browse the page-library without problems but it seems that a publication job crushed the page-library somehow as far as i found out in the logs. 
Solution: I created a new variation, copied my pages to this, deleted the german variation, and copied the pages back.. No it seems to work perfect ;)

Comment: Super!! This happend again.... -.-' Seems to be true that nobody does have a solution....